# How to assign same keys as a value to the repeated keys in dictionary

Tags: python

If the dictionary is like

```
my_dict = {0:"Sara", 1:"Jessica",2:"monica", 3:"sara" }
```

is it possible to replace the value of key 3 (3: "sara") sara should be replaced with the key of 0.

for example
the dictionary is like,

```
my_dict = {0:"Sara", 1:"Jessica",2:"monica", 3:0 }
```

Comment: "The key of 0" - 0 is the key.

Comment: Yes, how to assign the key as a value so that we don't have repeated values.

Comment: is `"Sara"` and `"sara"` same or different?

Comment: @AhmadMahmood so `my_dict[3] = 0`?

Comment: "Sara" and "sara" bth are same

Comment: Please provide more info. how you create the dict? Are the keys always numbers? Numbers from 0? Is the order of addition important? What should be left, `0:"Sara"` or `3:"sara"`? Why? .......... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about it like this:

```
my_dic = {0: "Sara", 1: "Jessica", 2: "monica", 3: "sara"}

first_occurance = {}

for k, v in my_dic.items():
    v = v.upper()
    if v not in first_occurance:
        first_occurance[v] = k

result_dict = {}
occured = []

for k, v in my_dic.items():
    upper_v = v.upper()
    if upper_v in occured:
        result_dict[k] = first_occurance[upper_v]
    else:
        result_dict[k] = v
        occured.append(upper_v)

result_dict

# {0: 'Sara', 1: 'Jessica', 2: 'monica', 3: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools and groupby to do so. I ended up with the solution bellow but there may be faster ones :

```
import itertools

my_dict = {0: "Sara", 1: "Jessica", 2: "monica", 3: "sara"}

# groupby need the iterable to be sorted so we need to sort by the value because we want to regroup nodes with the same
# value. Also we call lower() because uppercase does not matter in the matching
sorted_dict = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda node: node[1].lower())
# groupby the node value
groupby = itertools.groupby(sorted_dict, key=lambda node: node[1].lower())
# for each group
for key, value in groupby:
    # get the list of node for this key (here key are either sara, jessica or monica)
    value_list = list(value)
    # duplicated are every element in the list after the first one
    for duplicate in value_list[1:]:
        # for each duplicate, we modify the initial dict by setting the value 
        # to the key of the first element of the value_list
        my_dict[duplicate[0]] = value_list[0][0]

print(my_dict)
# {0: 'Sara', 1: 'Jessica', 2: 'monica', 3: 0}
```

At the end the node "3" has been modified in order to set the value as the key of the first "sara" found.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

symply using dict comprehension:

```
my_dict = {0:"Sara", 1:"Jessica",2:"monica", 3:"sara" }
my_dict = {key: value.lower() for key, value  in enumerate(list(my_dict.values()))}
new_dict = {key: (value if key == list(my_dict.values()).index(value) else list(my_dict.keys())[list(my_dict.values()).index(value)]) for key, value in enumerate(list(my_dict.values()))}
print(new_dict)
```

output:

```
{0: 'sara', 1: 'jessica', 2: 'monica', 3: 0}
```

**Note:**

it will work only with numeric key sorted to 0 from infinite, and with string values, and it will lower all values so it won't be case sensitive, but for your case will work and it will surely be the most pythonic way to achive you objective

to make it case sensitive revove the second line